# Convert x hour(s) y min(s) into z minutes using Java

Tags: java, time, duration

I have fetched google maps ETAs (that is, durations) for some routes in the format of `x hour(s) y min(s)`, and also if x > 24 then this format changes into `u day(s) v hour(s)`.

Now I want to compare these values to some other ETAs so all I need to do is convert these format value into a minutes-only value.

Such as I have a value as 4 hours 34 mins, I want to change it into minutes using Java or such as 1 hour 1 min to minutes, there are records where hour indicated as 1 hour and 3 hours and same for mins and days.

Comment: When you say estimated time of arrival, I am thinking a clock hour, like 6:34 AM tomorrow. But I think you are really meaning a duration, how long the ride takes, rather than when it ends. Correct?

Comment: yes right i mean a duration

Answer (score 1):

```
    Duration lessThanADay = Duration.ofHours(4).plusMinutes(34);
    long minutes = lessThanADay.toMinutes();
```

This yields 274 minutes. The case for more than 24 hours is similar:

```
    Duration moreThanADay = Duration.ofDays(1).plusHours(3);
```

This time `toMinutes()` returns 1620.

You can apply and mix `plusHours()` and `plusMinutes()`freely depending on which input numbers you’ve got.

**EDIT:** Your input strings are a bit more complicated. The `Duration` class can parse strings in ISO 8601 format, it goes like `PT3H23M` for a period of time of 3 hours 23 minutes. It may feel a little odd at first. However, we can fix your strings into this format:

```
private static Duration toDuration(String durationString) {
    durationString = durationString.replaceAll(" days?", "D");
    durationString = durationString.replaceAll(" hours?", "H");
    durationString = durationString.replaceAll(" mins?", "M");
    durationString = durationString.replace(" ", "");
    if (durationString.contains("D")) {
        durationString = durationString.replaceFirst("\\d+D", "P$0T");
    } else {
        durationString = "PT" + durationString;
    }
    return Duration.parse(durationString);
}
```

Let’s try this method on your example strings from the comment:

```
    System.out.println(toDuration("3 hours 23 mins"));
    System.out.println(toDuration("2 hours 56 mins"));
    System.out.println(toDuration("1 hour 1 min"));
    System.out.println(toDuration("1 day 18 hours"));
```

This prints:

```
PT3H23M
PT2H56M
PT1H1M
PT42H
```

So all of your strings have been recognized and parsed.

For the comparison, you don’t *need* to convert to minutes since `Duration` objects have a natural ordering and can be compared using `compareTo`, for example:

```
    if (lessThanADay.compareTo(moreThanADay) < 0) {
        System.out.println("Less");
    }
```

(This prints `Less`.) You may find it more natural to compare the `long` minutes values using `<` and `>`, though.

Comment: but i have fetches values like that 3 hours 23 mins, 2 hours 56 mins, 1 hour 1 min, 1 day 18 hours and much more, so can i apply above formula in loop and how to handle hour and hours

Comment: @shivamgoyal See my edit in the middle of the answer.

Comment: private static Duration toDuration (strText)  {
    strText = strText.replaceAll(" days?", "D");
    strText = strText.replaceAll(" hours?", "H");
    strText = strText.replaceAll(" mins?", "M");
    strText = strText.replace(" ", "");
    if(strText.contains("D")) {
     strText = strText.replaceFirst("\\d+D", "P$0T");
    }
    else {
     strText = "PT" + strText;
    }
    return Duration.parse(strText);
   }
   System.out.println(toDuration(strText));
there is an error in very first line of this code as invalid modifier for toDuration

Comment: Works here. Just a wild guess, did you put the method in the correct place in your program? Inside a class, but not inside any other method.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it on space...

```
String s[]="3 hours 23 mins".split(" ")
```

Then I'd just normalize everything to minutes

```
int minutes=0;
for(int i=0;i<=2;i+=2) {
   if(s[i+1].startsWith("min"))
       minutes+=s[i]
   if(s[i+1].startsWith("hour"))
       minutes+=s[i]*60
   if(s[i+1].startsWith("day"))    
       minutes+=s[i]*60*24
}
```

If you were to put the lookup values into a map you could cut 2/3 from that loop, I'd do it that way in Groovy where the additional syntax would be minimal but in java it's a 50/50 if the added awkwardness loweres the redundancy enough to be worth it.